# how to label various content of parabola in tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can someone pls help with a basic and simplest code to draw a parabola "3x^2-x-4" showing all the grid lines, axis of symmetry, roots and marking the vertex with the help of arrows, dashed lines and proper coordinates. 
i am only able to draw till grid lines and all the stuff which available inline is too complicated. pls help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the code you wrote (with the grid lines) till now (as minimum as possible) to help us start from somewhere.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}

\draw(-4,0)--(4,0);
\draw(0,-4)--(0,4);

\draw[step=1cm,gray, very thin](-3.5,-3.5)grid(3.5,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: See `pgfplots` package!

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.25cm,gray,thick]
(-2,-2)grid(2,2);

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) parabola(-1,1);
  \draw (0,0) parabola (1,1);
  \draw (0,0) parabola (2,4);
  \draw (0,0) parabola (-2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}                                          This is another example which i was  trying to fit a aparabola on grid lines; but grpah is somewhere grid lines are somewhere else..

Comment: @Misha edit the question and add the code to it. Please add minimal working example. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: As start try the following: 
`\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid, no marks, domain=-4:4.3]
\addplot {3*x*x - x -4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
`

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\t)=3*\t*\t - \t -4;}]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,{f(1/6)-0.5}) -- (0,{f(-4/3)+0.5});
 \draw[-stealth] (-5/3,0) -- (2,0);
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-4/3:5/3,smooth] (\t,{f(\t)});
 \draw[dashed] ({1/6},{f(1/6)-0.5}) -- ({1/6},{f(5/3)+0.5});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` has a dashed symmetry axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, svgnames, border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic, xunit=2, yunit=1.5, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=4pt, linejoin=1, plotstyle=curve, plotpoints=200}%
\newpsstyle{gridstyleA}{gridlabels=0pt, gridcolor=LightSteelBlue, subgridcolor =LightSteelBlue!60, gridwidth=0.4pt, subgridwidth=0.4pt, subgriddiv=5, subgriddots=10}

\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-2.99, -4.8)(3, 4.8)
\psaxes[linecolor=SteelBlue, arrows=->, showorigin=false, tickcolor=black, xlabelPos=dr](0,0)(-2.8, -4.8)(2.8, 4.8)[$x$,-135] [$y$,-135]
\uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed3}
\psplot{-5}{5}{3*x^2-x-4}
\psset{linecolor=black, linewidth=0.6pt}
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed](*0.167 {3*x^2-x-4})
\psline{<->}(-0.833, -4.083)(1.167, -4.083)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you used standalone class?

Comment: It's just an old habit to compile pstricks figures as independent files, and incorporate them with `\includegraphics`.  This makes compilation of the main file faster. But you can incorporate the code in any other document class.

Comment: ! Package auto-pst-pdf Error:"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:auto-pst-pdf will not work!.See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}            I get this error if i try your code. What does this mean?

Comment: `pdflatex` cannot make the computations required by postscript, so it has  to outsource the compilation to `latex` (the standard way is with the sequence `latex->dvips->pstopdf`). You have to add the switch `--enable-shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` to the configuration of the `pdflatex` compiler (this is usually done through your editor). Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Bernard. I am trying to label the roots and vertex of it.

Comment: One root is already labelled. Just use `\uput` for the other root and the vertex.

Comment: what is the significance of [dl] with \uput?

Comment: Below, on the left –in other words, SW direction.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

With an almost minimal `Tikz` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[gray!20] (-4,-5) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-5)--(0,4) node[above] () {$y$}; 
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] () {\small \bfseries \x};
        \foreach \y in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4} \draw (.1,\y)--(-.1,\y) node[left] () {\small \bfseries \y};
        \node () at (-.2,-.2) {$O$};
        \clip (-4,-5) rectangle (4,4);
        \draw[line width=3pt,cyan] plot[domain=-4:4,smooth]     (\x,{3*\x*\x-\x-4});
        \draw[dashed,line width=1pt] (1/6,-5)--(1/6,6);
        \draw[<->,line width=1pt] (1/6-1,-49/12)--(1/6+1,-49/12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```